# Is it possible to download packages for Win32 in zip format?

Tags: python, package

Everything seems to be only available in self-extracting `.exe`. My company blocks executable files from being downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close. Download the source - a `.tar.gz` archive, so you need something beyond window's built-in zip handling to unpack it - and run `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to "easy-install" the package

Comment: ... if you have it installed, of course. Is some version of `easy_install` included in the standard windows distribution?

Comment: easy_install comes with Distribute, which you install by downloading http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py and running it. No Exe files anywhere. :)

Comment: @delan: 'Included in the standard windows distribution'. Microsoft including a non microsoft product with windows? Hah!

Answer (score 0):

The self-extracting exe is only necessary if the package contains C-code that needs to be compiled, and you don't have a compiler. Otherwise you can use the source package, which often is a tgz.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a "self-extracting" zip file you can just change the .exe extension to .zip and then unzip it with any standard zip file handling utility...assuming you can at least download .exe files. If you can't, you might be able to rename them *during* the download process (i.e. via a "Save As" dialog).